# How to add entity to many to many relation in Slick

Tags: scala, many-to-many, slick

I have a following table defined in Slick, it connects two entities by id, so it consists of two ids which together form primary key. I don't know how to add new value to the table.

```
trait CaptionNounComponent extends CaptionComponent with NounComponent {
  self: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] =>

  import profile.api._

  class CaptionNounTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[CaptionNoun](tag, "caption_noun") {

    def * : ProvenShape[CaptionNoun] = (captionId, nounId) <> ((CaptionNoun.apply _).tupled, CaptionNoun.unapply)

    def nounId: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("NOUN_ID")

    def captionId: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("CAPTION_ID")

    def pk = primaryKey("primaryKey", (captionId, nounId))

    def nounFK =
      foreignKey("noun_fk", nounId, TableQuery[NounTable])(_.id)

    def captionFK =
      foreignKey("caption_fk", captionId, TableQuery[CaptionTable])(_.id)
  }
}
```

Normally I would try something like:

```
private val keyTable = TableQuery[CaptionNounTable]

  def addKeys(keys: CaptionNoun): Future[Int] = db.run {
    (keyTable returning keyTable.map(_.pk)) += keys
  }
```

but in this case it does not work

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to import

```
  import profile.api._
```

That seems to resolve the problem